# ¿Como extraer un campo de una tabla en un trigger en sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero asignarle al precio un valor de una tabla, pero cuando se dispara el trigger asigna el valor null al precio, a continuación mi trigger, la consulta me regresa una tabla con un el nombre de la columna y una tupla con un único valor, pero tengo problemas para asignar ese valor

```
Delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER alquila_calPrecio
before INSERT 
ON alquila
FOR EACH ROW
    begin
        SET NEW.precio = (SELECT costo FROM coche,alquila WHERE coche.matricula = alquila.matricula);
    END;
// Delimiter;
```

Comment: Seguro que la sub consulta solo retorna un valor?

Comment: El problema es que estás relacionand dos tablas (coches y alquila) sin un join que la relacione. La solución de esa query sería `SELECT costo FROM coche JOIN alguila ON coche.matricula = alquila.matricula`. De esta forma, relacionas las tablas `coche` y `alquila` en relación donde la matrícula del coche y de alquila son la misma.

Comment: Lo modifique al siguiente query, pero me sigue dando null:                                                                      SELECT costo FROM coche JOIN alquila ON coche.matricula = alquila.matricula WHERE coche.matricula = NEW.matricula